# how to fix "failed to compile" in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to make a reactjs website and it's showing failed to compile. I get few errors that few of those states and function are undefined, what could be the solution. I pasted the code below. 
what my code does is, you input title and description and then it'll save the posts when i click on the save button. I tried binding snippetDescription to the saving function but everything is undefined.

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

handleRequest = async (postId) => {  //passed postId here
  const post = this.state;
  const request = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };
  if (postId != null) {
    post["id"] = postId;
  }
  try {
    const response = await fetch("/api/updateposts", {
      ...request,
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    if (data.status === 200) {
      console.log("success", "post saved successfully!");
    } else {
      console.log(
        "danger",
        "An error has occured while updating the post. Please try again"
      );
    }
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    console.log(
      "danger",
      "An error has occured while updating the post. Please try again"
    );
  }
};

handlePost = (postId) => {            //passed postId here
  if (postId == null) {
    return handleRequest("/api/savepost");
  }
  return handleRequest("/api/updatepost");
};
const analysis = (snippetDescription) => {   //passed snippetDescription
  fetch("/api/analyse", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      snippetdesc: "snippetDescription"
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(
      textdata => {
        this.setState({
          textdata: textdata.data,
          textlen: snippetDescription.split(" ").length
        });
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
};

export default class MainText extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      id: null,
      snippetDescription: "",
      textlen: 0
    };
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <>  
           <input
                type="text"
                id="titletext"
                placeholder="Enter title here"
                limit-to="64"
                className="inptxt"
                onChange={title => this.setState({ title })}
              ></input>
            <span class="itemcenter">              
              <Link to="/about">
                <Button
                  className="btn savebtn"
                  onClick={() => handlePost({ ...this.state })}
                >
                  Save <i className="fas fa-save" />
                </Button>
              </Link>
            </span>
            <textarea
              class="textareaclass"
              placeholder="Enter your text here"
              onChange={snippetDescription =>
                this.setState({ snippetDescription })
              }
            ></textarea>
     </>
     )}
```

this is the error message that i get

```
Failed to compile.

./src/component/Text.js
  Line 5:     'handleRequest' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 15:    'postId' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 16:   'postId' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 43:    'handlePost' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 44:    'postId' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 45:   'handleRequest' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 47:   'handleRequest' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 119:  'snippetDescription' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 287:  'handlePost' is not defined          no-undef
```

are my states not being passed to the functions? also how is my function handleRequest and handlePost not defined as well?

Update:
I have moved all the code(functions) inside the react component, added this.handlePost and it still shows the same error.

```
./src/component/mainText.js
  Line 31:    'postId' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 32:   'postId' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 59:    'postId' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 60:   'handleRequest' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 62:   'handleRequest' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 134:  'snippetDescription' is not defined  no-undef
```

New update:

I have edited the functions now and passed the values to the functions which I didn't pass before in the above code, so now the only error I'm getting is handleRequest not defined. should I declare handleRequest somewhere?

```
Line 60:   'handleRequest' is not defined       no-undef
Line 62:   'handleRequest' is not defined       no-undef
```

Updae: I have added this.handlerequest.bind(this) so it's not showing errors anymore. the binding was right, i hope. can someone verify it

```
 handlePost = postId => {
 if (postId == null) {
      return this.handleRequest("/api/savepost").bind(this);
    }
    return this.handleRequest("/api/updatepost").bind(this);
  };
```

Comment: please declare all variables which missing, in you cod. set the initial values for.
That is: `postId `, `handleRequest `, `snippetDescription `.
`handleRequest` is function, so u can declare the empty function

Comment: i did declare snippetDescription, postId in states already. where should I declare them again

Comment: but in your example, I can't see it

Answer (score 0):

Move all the related code in  errors to scope of React Component. You can not declare and use  functions and state out of react component class.
In event handlers of component you must call the component functions with 'this.' context.  for example:

```
  onClick={() => this.handlePost....}
```

Comment: I moved the functions inside the react component and it still doesn't help.  Now I get this error. Line 119:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

> 119 | const analysis = () => {

Comment: I understood, remove the const before analysis declaration of function.

Comment: how do I change the onChange function? where should I add 'this' there?

Comment: As I wrote in answer

Comment: ochange  leave without changes

Comment: it isn't doing anything. still showing the same error as you can see the updated post. I added this.handlePost

Comment: You have basic errors in use of functions in component

Comment: you got the direction from my answer if

Comment: I don't know, I tried looking at everything, couldn't figure out where it went wrong. can you point out the basic errors?

Comment: should I bind the functions in constructor?

Comment: I have made the changes now and have no errors now. Is my binding correct with the the handleRequest function